# Rasa init: "Can't find specified module"

Tags: rasa

I'm new to using rasa and I encounter my first issue with it, when I try to run `rasa init --no-prompt` or `rasa init` I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 193, in *run_module_as_main
> "**main**", mod_spec)   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\runpy.py",
> line 85, in *run_code
> exec(code, run_globals)   File "G:\rasa\venv\Scripts\rasa.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
>
> File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\rasa_*main**.py", line 82, in
> main
> set_log_level(log_level)   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\common.py", line 71, in
> set_log_level
> update_tensorflow_log_level()   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\rasa\utils\common.py", line 112, in
> update_tensorflow_log_level
> import tensorflow as tf   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init*_.py", line 101, in
>
> from tensorflow_core import *   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core_*init*_.py", line 40,
> in 
> from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util   File "", line 983, in *find_and_load
>
> File "", line 959, in
> *find_and_load_unlocked   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init**.py", line 50, in
> **getattr**
> module = self.*load()   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_*init**.py", line 44, in
> *load
> module = *importlib.import_module(self.**name**)   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\importlib_*init**.py",
> line 127, in import_module
> return *bootstrap.*gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python_*init**.py",
> line 95, in 
> from tensorflow.python import keras   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras_*init**.py",
> line 27, in 
> from tensorflow.python.keras import models   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras_*init**.py",
> line 27, in 
> from tensorflow.python.keras import models   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\models.py",
> line 26, in 
> from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import sequential   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\sequential.py",
> line 28, in 
> from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training.py",
> line 46, in 
> from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import training_arrays   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py",
> line 41, in 
> from scipy.sparse import issparse  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top   File
> "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy_*init**.py", line 136, in
>
> from . import *distributor_init   File "g:\rasa\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy_distributor_init.py", line 61,
> in 
> WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\ctypes_*init**.py",
> line 364, in **init**
> self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode) OSError: [WinError 126] No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado

OS: Windows 10

Python version: 3.7

I have follow the instructions from the Rasa's website for the installation.
https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/installation

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio C++ Build tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this a long time but forgot to answer my own question. I did try to reinstall python (different versions of it), I try to create virtual enviroments without luck. The thing that worked for me was installing anaconda and run the project within conda enviroment. I couldn't figured out what was the missing thing in a regular python setup.

Answer (score 1):

The Module Not Found error may occur when you're using Windows or macOS for local development.

Modules are integral to the Python language. Modules let you break down your code into multiple files. This helps maintain the readability and maintainability of a codebase.It’s common to encounter a ModuleNotFoundError when working with modules.

you need a file named **init**.py (two underscores on each side) in every folder in the hierarchy, so one in src/ and one in model/. This is what python looks for to know that it should access a particular folder. The files are meant to contain initialization instructions but even if you create them empty this will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue with rasa-x.

Try this:

```
pip install -U pip & rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple --use-deprecated=legacy-resolver
```

Versions:

```
pip               :         21.1.2
Rasa Version      :         2.7.0
Minimum Compatible Version: 2.6.0
Rasa SDK Version  :         2.7.0
Rasa X Version    :         0.40.1
Python Version    :         3.8.9
```